# Where to find a customizable full event / booking calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, calendar

I am looking for an event / booking calendar where in each cell / day is customizable (we can put whatever we like).

I've mostly seen calendars which allow you to input event as text. However, we need to put in four text fields and display it in a certain way for each cell.

Is there a plug-in (jquery or something else) that does this?

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/?](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve all of the functionality you're looking for you're going to need to make some modifications but this should do the trick.

**Features**

- Select on a day-by-day basis and set criteria for each day
- Unlimited amount of usages on your website or on your webpage.
- Front End and Back End versions.
- Each version can be completely customizable separately from CSS .
- Auto resizable.
- You can change the language.
- Compatible with any server side script.

Please see: [Booking Calendar Pro](http://codecanyon.net/item/booking-calendar-pro-jquery-plugin/244645).

Also - it's not the 'prettiest' solution so you're probably going to need to take some time to dress it up. This is a plugin I've used in previous projects and was unable to find anything that offered similar or better functionality.